# Cordova app not building - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, cordova, ant, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get my cordova app to build in VS2015 Preview - Currently though it just spits out a www folder with empty js, css and img folders.

All dependencies (Ant, Java, Android SDK, cordova) are installed, all environmental variables are set and behaving correctly.

**Updated BUILD LOG**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1namKw-GO53QzM1MEdScHBzanc/view?usp=sharing

Can anyone please offer any insight as i am currently going insane :(

Comment: Hi Ellen,  Can you turn on diagnostic logging and output following these instructions and post the results? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, Ellen was editing the post (Thank you, mysterious overflower ;)) 

Edited post with output. Thank you for your help!